# render a different view on jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i'm new to development so please be patient if i ask a ridiculous question...

i'm trying to post `id` to my action result on drop down value changed using `$.post` which works fine but it returns to the same view, but i want it to render a different view

here is my jquery code its in home/index

```
 $('#select-supplier').change(function (e) {
                var atrVal = $(this).val();
                if (atrVal != '') {

                    $.post('<%=Url.Action("SupplierSelect","Supplier")%>', { id: atrVal });


                    // alert('value changed ' + atrVal);
                } else { alert('please  select a value'); }


            });
```

here is my controller side(SupplierController)

```
 public class SupplierController : Controller
    {               
        public ActionResult SupplierSelect(int id)
        {
            //some code
            return View();
        }

    }
```

instead of rendering the `SupplierSelect` view it comes back to the home/index from where it was called

tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post sends a (HTTP POST) request to the server and the response is returned to the post method, not to the browser. It sounds like what you want is to redirect to another page from javascript. So instead of the post, you need to do a redirect which is done like this:

```
window.location = '<%= Url.Action(...)';
```

Comment: is there another way other than the java-script to redirect on selected value changed of the dropdown list??

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're taking any action on the success of the $.post() call. Ideally, you would be populating some other element on the page with the returned html.

like

```
$.post('<%=Url.Action("SupplierSelect","Supplier")%>', { id: atrVal }, function(data) {
  $('#supplier_div').html(data);
});
```

if it's supposed to go to a completely different page, then you just want to submit the form and not use AJAX maybe??

Comment: i dont want to get a callback just navigate to the new view... like `html.actionlink` hope im clear enough :| ... its not necessary to use `$.post()` if there is another way...